# Can not sync project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have quite strage error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ExoPlayerTest'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
               > Remote host closed connection during handshake
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.71.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.71.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.71.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.71.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.71.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.71.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.71.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.71.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.71.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.71.pom'.
               > Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

I can not sync any project on my system from 2 different versions of Android Studio.
Seems like it cannot connect to repositories, while I have an internet connection.

Comment: This error seems that you have opened the project which is not created by the current system. Either you should delete the current project and freshly import project rather opening it. If this is not the project as per above scenario, You have to manually change the gradle versions, classpaths, kotlin version which are currently available in your system. This doesn't require any internet though. Comment if you face the same after doing any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were proxy properties in /home//.gradle config file.
After deleting theem it started to work properly.